# CSS div without edges

Tags: html, css

How could I achieve such thing like this image:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysPrQ.png)

This is what I have for now:

```
              <div class="icon-social">
                <div>
                  <i class="fa-brands fa-discord fa-xl" style="color:white;"></i>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="icon-social">
                <div>
                  <i class="fa-brands fa-twitter fa-xl" style="color:white;"></i>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="icon-social">
                <div>
                  <img src="https://storage.googleapis.com/opensea-static/Logomark/Logomark-Transparent%20White.svg" width="24" alt="">
                </div>
              </div>
```

css

```
.icon-social{
text-align: center;
width: 3.5em;
background-color: #e8aec6;
padding: 0.5em;
margin-right: 1em;
/* transform: skewY(-20deg); */
```

}

result:

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ktaM.png)

I tried to work with `transform: skewY(-20deg);` but did not work the way I want to do so.

Comment: I was answering, in the while they closed the question. By the way you can use `clip-path` CSS property: `clip-path: polygon(25% 0, 100% 0, 100% 75%, 75% 100%, 0 100%, 0 25%);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [clip-path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) property with a custom path. Looks like you only need 6 points, so it can by done by hand using `M` commands or using a `polygon`.